# Fi-Ware Bigdata configuration

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-cygnus

I'm reading a tutorial to Bigdata installationg over Fi-Ware.

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/develop/flume/README.md

I've completed susccesfully steps up to "Installing Cygnus and its dependencies". I've realized there is a new Cygnus version (0.3 instead of 0.2.1 used in the tutorial). I'd like to know if it is necesary to acomplish another step related to dependences installation.

I found in the tutorial the next paragraph

OrionCKANSink dependencies

These are the packages you will need to install under APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/libext if you did not included them in the Cygnus package:

```
json-simple-1.1.jar
OrionHDFSSink dependencies
```

These are the packages you will need to install under APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/libext if you did not included them in the Cygnus package:

```
hadoop-core-0.20.0.jar (or higher)
hive-exec-0.12.0.jar
hive-jdbc-0.12.0.jar
hive-metastore-0.12.0.jar
hive-service-0.12.0.jar
hive-common-0.12.0.jar
hive-shims-0.12.0.jar
```

These packages are not necessary to be installed since they are already included in the Flume bundle (they have been listed just for informative purposes):

```
httpclient-4.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.2.jar
```

In addition, as already said, remember to overwrite the APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar package with this one:

```
libthrift-0.9.1.jar
```

Finally, if you are planning to use the OrionMySQLSink, include the latest MySQL connector in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/libext:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

Is there an easier way to install and configure cygnus?? It seems to difficult to use Bigdata with fi-ware.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, some important remarks:

- [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/flume) is not the FI-WARE Big Data enabler, it is a connector in charge of storing the real-time context data managed by [Orion Context Broker](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker) in several persistent storages for historic datasets generation. One of such storages may be the [Big Data](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos) enabler, but it could also be a [MySQL server](http://www.mysql.com/) o a [CKAN](http://ckan.org/) deployment.
- At the moment of writing this response, there is no official 0.3 release for Cygnus, it is due to end of June 2014: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues?milestone=2&state=open

Being said that, installing Cygnus is quite simple. Basically, you have to install [Apache Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) and then build the Cygnus jar which will contain additional classes for Flume.

**Cygnus 0.1** building is as simple as doing:

```
$ cd /path/to/cygnus/folder
$ /path/to/maven/bin/mvn package
$ cp target/cygnus-0.1.jar /path/to/flume/lib
```

Nothing else is required since such version has no support for MySQL nor Hive tables automatic creation.

**Cygnus 0.2** and **Cygnus 0.2.1** both require several third-party libraries, but most of them are pacakged with the Cygnus classes themselves by using this command, as documented in the README:

```
$ cd /path/to/cygnus/folder
$ /path/to/maven/bin/mvn clean compile assembly:single
$ cp target/cygnus-0.2.x-jar-with-dependencies.jar /path/to/flume/plugins.d/cygnus/lib
```

The only additional thing you have to do is to upgrade the Flume libthrift library and to copy the MySQL connector in `/path/to/flume/plugins.d/cygnus/libext`. The list of libraries you've found in the README are listed just for documentation purposes (as stated there).

Anyway, we are working on the generation of RPMs automating the above steps. So stay tuned!

Comment: Following the README file when I clone from 
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors.git
I get cygnus-0.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Where can I download the 0.2.x version?

Anyway I have followed all steps and in the Running final step I get a Java error with the class

3)] Error while configuring HTTPSource. Exception follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler

 es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink, class: es.tid.fiware.fiwareconnectors.cygnus.sinks.OrionHDFSSink

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to get specific versions, just checkout them after the clone step with `git checkout release/x.y.z`. Of course, always follow the README according to the specific release.